# Sci-Fi movie where an alien construct is operated by the pilot dipping his hands into strange liquid

Tags: story-identification, movie, spaceship

Can you help identify a sci-fi movie that this scene is from? I made a reference to a sci-fi scene where a character pilots an alien ship or some other construct by dipping his hands into a strange goo. The character is sitting in a pilot seat, and the basins of goo are at the end of either arm of the chair. As I talk to people, this is certainly a remembered scene, but I can't find a clip or the source of it. I originally thought it was *District 9*, but it looks like all of the ship control is done using holographic displays. Thanks for any help!

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  Where and when did you see this?

Comment: One very recent example of this is Quantumania, where Michael Douglas' character operations a glider in the way you described. But it seems a bit unlikely that you are asking for something contemporary.

Comment: @DavidW I remember seeing this scene around 10 years ago, though the movie may be older. In my mind, the aesthetic seems akin to District 9 or Prometheus, but I haven't been able to find the scene.

Comment: What colour is the goo?  (The Hullen interfaces in Killjoys immediately sprang to mind, but that's a TV series rather than a movie and too recent, based on the supplementary comment.)

Comment: The BSG reboot has echos of the technology, but not a pilot seat as I recall.

Comment: I'll have to scan through D9 again - I'm pretty sure the chair does have good pots as well as the other holographic interfaces - and TVTropes agrees. Surprisingly, not many other movies/TV shows listed with this particular interface - it feels like it would be a fairly common trope

Answer (score 15, accepted):

There *is* [a scene in *District 9*](https://youtu.be/BbxF5WT1IFo?t=185) where Wiklus sticks his mutated hand into a jelly-filled receptacle on the shuttle as he starts it up in order to escape.

[image: Wiklus sticks his mutated left hand into a hole filled with slightly glowing yellowish-brown gel]

Comment: That looks like the one! I was flipping through scenes, thinking it was the final takeoff or even the mech scene, but I forgot about this one. I appreciate your being thorough, I should've stuck with my gut!